# How to make UITextView in section header adjust its height to its content

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I cannot get this to work. I am using autolayout on the current view controller. I have a UITableView that has section headers and each section header has UITextView  that has text that varies in length depending on the section. I cannot make it enlarge its height automatically to fit the contents so there will be no need for scroll (its contents are attributed text)

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //UITextView *tv = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    //tv.editable = NO;        
    //tv.attributedText =  [self millionaireResults][section][@"header"];    
    //return tv;

    return [self millionaireResults][section][@"headerview"]; //this is a uitextview
}

// this did not workeither 
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UITextView *tv = [self millionaireResults][section][@"headerview"];
    return tv.frame.size.height; 

}
```

How can this problem be solved?

**I updated the code per the suggestion of Michael below**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer that worked for me

1. When you are creating the UITextView, you must set the scrollEnabled
   to false.
2. Your UITextView must be given the width that covers horizontal space otherwise auto size calculation are off (sometimes it is sometimes it is not, i think depending on wordbreak or something, but it was inconsistent!) and only fixes itself if you rotate the device to force redraw
3. In the heightForHeaderInSection method, you must get the
   sizeThatFits and return its height as the height of your text view

Here is the height calculation (I found this on this site http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial )

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UITextView *tv1 = (UITextView *)[self millionaireResults][section][@"headerview"];
    // sizethatfits calculates the perfect size for this UITextView 
    // if you gave your UITextView full width
    CGSize goodsize = [tv1 sizeThatFits:tv1.frame.size];
    return goodsize.height+4; // here 4 is not necessary, i just put it as an offset
}
```

Here is the code that creates those UITextView objects

```
for (int i = 0; i < [milarr count]; i++) {        
    UITextView *tv = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    tv.editable = NO;
    tv.attributedText = milarr[i];
    // labelTopTitle and this table in question have same width in an autoLayouted view
    // so i am giving width of labelTopTitle to let UITextView cover full available
    // horizontal space
    tv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.labelTopTitle.frame.size.width,FLT_MAX);
    //tv.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    //tv.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    tv.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [results  addObject:@{@"headerview": tv,
                         @"rows":@[...]
                         }
     ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your "`UITextView *tv`" object a property and then you can do something like this (assuming you only have exactly one section to your table view):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return (self.tv.frame.size.height);
}
```

If you have more sections (which is appears you do), you should make that property a NSArray of UITextView objects.

This also means you need to set the contents of your "`tv`" object *before* "`viewForHeaderInSection:`" gets called.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Can you tell me why it worked? Only difference is that instead of creating the UITextView object inside viewForHeaderInSection: ... method, I created them as an NSArray property as you suggested. What was wrong with creating in that delegate method? I would really appreciate the answer if you know.

Comment: because `heightForHeaderInSection` gets called long before `viewForHeaderInSection` gets called.  iOS needs to know how tall the table and it's contents are going to be before actually drawing the individual cells and section headers.

Comment: Hate to reopen this but above code does not work (I had a return 200;) in my code (my stupidity) that was making it fit the UITextView by returning that size. return self.tv.frame.size.height in your code above returns 0.000000 (Please don't get offended but I will have to uncheck the accepted answer until I get it to work)

Comment: Well remember I told you to actually populate the array of text view entries before "`heightForHeaderInSection`" gets called, right?

Comment: Yes I did that   They are populated in an nsarray property before table reloaddata is called. I am off to bed, late here in Turkey, will check again tomorrow

Comment: if you are creating your UITextView using "`UITextView *tv = [[UITextView alloc] init]];`", then there's no frame size set. You need to give it a frame size to work with before saving it in the array.

Comment: I gave an initial frame size like you suggested, but the height was whatever the height you give to frame because of the return (self.tv.frame.size.height); I posted my solution below.